# Undefined reference classes?

Tags: c++

Why is it giving me an undefined reference to `MySet::MySet()` while trying to print my `vector`? Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    class MySet{
        public:
            MySet(); 
            MySet(const vector<int> v3); 
        void printVector(const vector<int>& newMyVector);

    };

    int main()
    {
        vector<int> myVector;
        myVector.push_back(1);
        myVector.push_back(2);
        MySet m;
        m.printVector(myVector);
        return 0;
    }

    void MySet::printVector(const vector<int>& newMyVector){
        cout << "Vector: ";
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < newMyVector.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << newMyVector[i] << "|";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it giving me an undefined reference to `MySet::MySet()` while trying to print my `vector`?

You are creating an instance of `MySet` using

```
    MySet m;
```

That uses the default constructor. The default constructor has been declared in the class but it has not been defined. You can fix it by defining it.

```
MySet::MySet() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not include a definition for the constructor of MySet.  The constructor's name is `MySet::MySet()`.  So when you try to create an instance of the object, the compiler does not know what to do.  There are a couple solutions:

1. Remove the line right after "public:" that declares the constructor.  If you don't declare any constructors, your object will just use a default constructor supplied by the compiler which might be good enough.
2. Or, add a definition for the constructor somewhere in your program.
3. Or, you can change the line that declares `MySet::MySet()` so that it *also* defines it.

The code for option 2 would look like this, somewhere outside the class:

```
MySet::MySet()
{
  // do stuff here to construct object
}
```

The code for option 3 would look like this, somewhere inside the class:

```
MySet()
{
  // do stuff here to construct object
}
```